# How to sort textboxes and buttons selection order?

Tags: c#, forms, sorting, visual-studio-2008

I have a program like this:

[image]

When user is filling the form by pressing `Tab` button in keyboard, he should go to next button or textbox as shown in the image by red numbers.

But now after filling number 2, when I press Tab, it select a row in gridview!

After that... how can I sort this?

Comment: look for 'TabIndex' on your controls, and set it to whichever order you want ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the form open, go to the menu `View -> Tab Order`:

[image]

This then displays the current tab ordering on your form:

[image]

By clicking on the controls, you can define a **new** tab ordering:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `TabIndex` property of your controls. `TabStop` must be set to true. When pressing Tab, controls will be selected in the order of the `TabIndex` values you set.

Note that you do not need to set consecutive tab indices. You could even assign the same index to multiple controls. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx) for the exact behaviour.